# How to use "arrow-up" button to scroll in searched words history immediately after using isearch-forward

Tags: isearch, history

Is there any way to use "arrow-up" button to scroll in latest searched words **immediately** after using isearch-forward?
For now, in order to use the "arrow-up" key for this purpose, I am first required to do either of the following things:

1. M-p (mapped to isearch-ring-retreat in this context). Unfortunately my brain has limited capacity for remembering keyboard shortcuts, so I don't like this solution, "arrow-up" is more intuitive for me and I tend to remember it.
   Maybe I can bind the "arrow-up" key to isearch-ring-retreat **only** inside isearch context?
2. By clicking the mouse on the isearch prompt that had opened. This is inconvenient as it requires to use the mouse. Maybe I can change some isearch properties so that this happens by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after further investigation I actually found a solution that seems to achieve what I was looking for. I added the following to my init.el:

```
(progn
  (define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'isearch-ring-retreat )
  (define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<down>") 'isearch-ring-advance )
)
```

Credit goes to
http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_isearch_by_arrow_keys.html

Comment: Welcome to Emacs, land of the free! If you don't like something, rebind it.